# Inconsistent Whitespace Text Nodes in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, whitespace

The following source code alerts the following results:

**Internet Explorer 7**: 29
**Firefox 3.0.3**: 37 (correct)
**Safari 3.0.4 (523.12.9)**: 38
**Google Chrome 0.3.154.9**: 38

Please ignore the following facts:

- Webkit (Safari/Chrome) browsers insert an extra text node at the end of the body tag
- Internet Explorer doesn't have new lines in their whitespace nodes, like they should.
- Internet Explorer has no beginning whitespace node (there is obvious whitespace before the <form> tag, but no text node to match)

Of the tags in the test page, the following tags have no whitespace text nodes inserted in the DOM after them: `form`, `input[@radio]`, `div`, `span`, `table`, `ul`, `a`.

My question is: **What is it about these nodes that makes them the exception in Internet Explorer?**  Why is whitespace not inserted after these nodes, and is inserted in the others?

This behavior is the same if you switch the tag order, switch the doctype to XHTML (while still maintaining standards mode).

Here's a [link that gives a little background information](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/wrongWithIE/?chapter=Empty+Space), but no ideal solution.  There might not be a solution to this problem, I'm just curious about the behavior.

Thanks Internet,
Zach

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function countNodes()
        {
            alert(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].childNodes.length);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="countNodes()">
        <form></form>
        <input type="submit"/>
        <input type="reset"/>
        <input type="button"/>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="password"/>
        <input type="file"/>
        <input type="hidden"/>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
        <input type="radio"/>
        <button></button>
        <select></select>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <table></table>
        <ul></ul>
        <a></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Delayed shout out for node.children instead of node.childNodes: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.gaia/nkcH33D-Rvk https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IE tries to be helpful and hides text nodes that contain only whitespace.

In the following:

```
<p>
<input>
</p>
```

W3C DOM spec says that `<p>` has 3 child nodes ("\n", `<input>` and "\n"), IE will pretend there's only one.

The solution is to skip [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.nodeType) in all browsers:

```
var node = element.firstChild;
while(node && node.nodeType == 3) node = node.nextSibling;
```

Popular JS frameworks have functions for such things.

Comment: I've been running into a similar problem when trying to make my javascript code work in both FF and IE. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I'd say the reason it that it is IE. I don't think the programers had a specific intention to do it that way.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean "Why" in the "Why did they design it that way?" sense, I meant it in the "What is the correlation between these nodes to make them act this way?" sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the **table** tag is different between browsers.

e.g. which nodes does the default table auto-magically contain?

```
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure, that would change the childNodes of the table tag, I'm looking at the childNodes of the body.  Try the IE Developer Toolbar to see the whitespace nodes in the DOM.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try walking the DOM and see what each browser thinks that the document contains?

IE does a lot of "optimization" of the DOM. To get an impression of what this might look like, "Select all", "Copy" in IE, and then "Paste Alternate" in Visual Studio, You get the following:

```
<INPUT value="Submit Query" type=submit> 
<INPUT value=Reset type=reset> 
<INPUT type=button> 
<INPUT type=text> 
<INPUT value="" type=password> 
<INPUT type=file> 
<INPUT type=hidden>
<INPUT type=checkbox>
<INPUT type=radio>
<BUTTON type=submit></BUTTON> 
<SELECT></SELECT>
<TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA>
```

So it nukes some of the empty tags and adds some default attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Zachleat, I think I've found a solution to the problem. (I've taken liberty of moving the form elements into the form tag.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!--REF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/inconsistent-whitespace-text-nodes-in-internet-explorer -->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function countNodes()
    { alert(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].childNodes.length);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body onload="countNodes()">
  <form
    ><input type="submit"/
    ><input type="reset"/
    ><input type="button"/
    ><input type="text"/
    ><input type="password"/
    ><input type="file"/
    ><input type="hidden"/
    ><input type="checkbox"/
    ><input type="radio"/
    ><button></button
    ><select></select
    ><textarea></textarea
    ><div></div
    ><span></span
    ><table></table
    ><ul></ul
    ><a></a
  ></form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've split & strapped the closing gt (greater-than) brackets so they hug to the next tag, thus ensuring there are no ambiguous whitespaces.

It was a nice surprise that it worked for all (4 desktop) browsers tried so far, all reporting the same number of DOM nodes.

Comment: Yep, that’s one way to workaround the issue. I like to keep my markup a little cleaner than that, though, and would probably prefer one of the other solutions above.

Comment: I think it looks reasonable AND you're not randomly creating any extra redundant nodes! Having said that I just debugged & found that SAFARI [v.3] can sometimes randomly report wrong offsetTop thus messing things up if rely on it. But this is a different problem. The simple workaround still seem OK.