# Remove parent element after removing last child element

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a list of elements on a page, for the sake of discussion we can say I have the following:

```
<div id="group_01">
  <div id="entry_1-01">stuff <a href="delete">x</a></div>
  <div id="entry_1-02">stuff <a href="delete">x</a></div>
</div>

<div id="group_02">
  <div id="entry_2-01">stuff <a href="delete">x</a></div>
  <div id="entry_2-02">stuff <a href="delete">x</a></div>
</div>
```

The delete link calls an Ajax request and deletes the entry, after a succesful Ajax call, the entry div is removed from the page. My question is:

How can I remove the containing group div once all of it's entries have been deleted?

I hope that's a detailed enough question. I feel like this isn't anything new, yet two days of search has resulted in nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Before you delete the child element, get its parent, count the number of children, and then after deleting the child, delete the parent if the child count is zero. Here is a quicky piece of sample code:

```
function d (x)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(x);
    var p = e.parentNode;
    p.removeChild (e);
    if (p.childNodes.length == 0) {
        var pp = p.parentNode;
        pp.removeChild (p);
    }
}
```

I added onclicks to your divs like this:

```
<div id="group_01">
  <div id="entry_1_01">stuff 11<a onclick="d('entry_1_01');" href="#delete">x</a></div>
  <div id="entry_1_02">stuff 12<a onclick="d('entry_1_02');" href="#delete">x</a></div>
</div>
```

I also changed the link to "#delete". You could tidy this up in various ways.

Comment: Someone brought up an interesting side question by a comment they made. Does chlidNodes work for non XHTML doctypes?

Comment: @thisismat: It's not about doctype, just another cross-browser headache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/inconsistent-whitespace-text-nodes-in-internet-explorer Currently this answer does not work as intended cross-browser due to the whitespace in the markup shown.

Comment: Good information, thanks Crescent. The times I've used this I didn't have to deal with the whitespace issue so I never knew about this.

Comment: Would this fix the whitespace issue: if (p.childNodes.length === 0 && p.innerHTML.replace(/\s/,"")==="") ?

Answer (score 2):

A function like this should would work:

```
function removeNodeIfEmpty(node) {
   var container = document.getElementById(node);
   var nodeCount = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length, i++) {
       if (container.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
           nodeCount += 1;
       }
   }

   if (nodeCount < 1) {
     container.parentNode.removeChild(node);
   }
}
```

This should account for the whitespace issue.

Comment: Where do the `getChildNodes()` and `getParent()` methods come from? They aren't part of the ECMAScript binding of the DOM specification...

Comment: The getParent() function was a mistake which was corrected, the getChildNodes() I'm not sure honestly, but I have used it and tested it in the common browsers and had it work just fine. Good note though, now I'm curious if it's xhtml only or not.

Comment: Yeah, getChildNodes was a mistake as well, I went through some of my old code where I did what he's trying to do, been a while. What I actually need (edited) is http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/prop_element_childnodes.asp - interestingly enough, this works on elements if you're using xhtml.

Comment: You'll run into the same issue as @Kinopiko's answer wrt whitespace nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/inconsistent-whitespace-text-nodes-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks for the tip Crescent, I didn't know about this behavior. Modified the script a little to hopefully account for this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do something like this to remove an entry:

```
entryDiv.parentNode.removeChild(entryDiv);
```

then you should be able to use the following code to remove the group div when the last child is removed:

```
var groupDiv = entryDiv.parentNode;
groupDiv.removeChild(entryDiv);
if (!groupDiv.firstChild) {
    groupDiv.parentNode.removeChild(groupDiv);
}
```

...although you need to watch out for whitespace-only text nodes, if these entries haven't been created directly by script.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends what library you're using

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent#expr

should be a suitable expression