# JavaScript: DOM text nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

Take a look at the snippet below. Does it create a text node for the string "test" in the DOM? Can I select that node with jQuery for MooTools?

```
<div id="foobar">
    test <img />
</div>
```

Comment: I think one of (IE | FF) does create a node, and the other does not, but I forget which was which.

Comment: @Pekka: a textnode is created in both browsers. You're thinking of IE and *whitespace*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/inconsistent-whitespace-text-nodes-in-internet-explorer/311923#311923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//plain
var node = document.getElementById('foobar').childNodes[0];

//jquery
$("foobar").contents().eq(0);
```

this will give you a textnode which will include the whitespace around the text too

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

**Edit:**

```
$('#foobar').get(0).firstChild.data;
```