# Xml : Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to get information from an XML file with javascript but i have an error i cant resolve myself ...
"Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null "

I think it's a problem in my XML but i dont know where

Here is my javascript

```
 var map;
    var mod;

    var xmlDoc;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/xml");

    xhr.open('GET' , 'streamcontrol.xml');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;

        map = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('mapname');
        map = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('modname');

    }
```

And my Xml

```
<!DOCTYPE StreamControl>
<items>
 <timestamp>1408381485</timestamp>
 <mapname>hijacked</mapname>
 <modname>retd</modname>
</items>
```

Comment: Maybe xmlDoc is null?

Comment: You are trying to access the response before it was received. `onreadystatechange` is called multiple times, once for each state change. Have a look at a tutorial about XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971007/getting-xml-element-by-name-in-ajax-responsexml)!

Answer (score 2):

In the onreadystatechange function, maybe you should check the ready state :

```
var map;
var mod;

var xmlDoc;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.overrideMimeType("text/xml");

xhr.open('GET' , 'streamcontrol.xml');
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
        xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
        map = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('mapname');
        map = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('modname');
    }

}
```

readyState holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest :

> 0: request not initialized
>    1: server connection established
>    2: request received
>    3: processing request
>    4: request finished and response is ready

status is 200 when everything is ok, 404 is not found ...

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comments it works with the node doc , i post my script if it can help anybody :

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc('streamcontrol.xml');
map_node=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('mapname')[0].childNodes[0];
map = map_node.nodeValue;
```