# childNodes on <tr> has weird stuff in it, tripping me up

Tags: javascript, html

```
<tr id='tt_info_entry_2'>
  <th colspan=3>Read sigma[0]</th> 
  <th colspan=3>Read sigma[1]</th> 
</tr>
```

But in Chrome I get:

[image: screencap]

Note mysterious "Text" objects getting in the way of my for loop. There's three of them too. (only two `<th>`'s)

What's this?

P.S. I will use `getElementsByTagName('th')` on the `<tr>` to get a clean array. But still, I didn't have these weird text thingies pop up when I was doing all sorts of ninja stuff with `div`s. I can has explanation?

Comment: Can you post the HTML source? I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: It's right at the top... issue was, I assumed the children were all `th`'s when some of them were whitespace text objects. Turns out they really are text that I entered into the html source. I didn't connect the dots by examining the details listed by chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/inconsistent-whitespace-text-nodes-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whitespaces are also textNodes.
There are whitespaces before the 1st TH,after the 1st TH and after the 2nd TH (the line-breaks).

Use [**Element.children**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children) instead of **Element.childNodes** to retrieve only element-nodes.

Comment: Would have taken me hours to figure that one out. Thanks.

Comment: Btw `children` is specified in DOM4 as a property of the [Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-dom-20110915/#interface-element) interface. It appears that it has been unspecified until DOM4 since it's not mentioned in DOM 3 Core or Element Traversal.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to table rows and cells,  you should use:

- [`table.rows`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows)
- `row.cells` *The MDN docs link for `.cells` is broken right now, but as [@Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas) noted, it is listed [on this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement).*

They have wide browser support, and eliminate text node issues.

These give you browser compatibility back to `Firefox 3` and avoids some quirks `IE8` and lower have with `.children`.

[image]

Comment: @patrick `cells` doesn't seem to have a dedicated page on MDN, but it's on the list [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Thanks, I added that to the answer. I had come across that one, but in my quest, I noticed a few broken links at MDN. What's this world coming to?! I may need to start posting W3Schools links!!! *By the way, who is this "patrick" of whom you speak?*

Comment: OK, now you're scaring me `:)`

Comment: the page says "read-only HTMLCollection". So if I want to update the row's cells I still gotta do it the old way? It does seem to work but I don't want that read-only-ness to bite me in the ass later. Especially when getElementsByTagName works well.

Comment: @StevenLu: Any HTMLCollection or NodeList is *read-only*, including `.childNodes`, `.children` and the *NodeList* returned from `getElementsByTagName`. But all of these examples are "live lists". This means that they automatically update with changes to the DOM. The `.rows` and `.cells` properties are no exception. You'll always have a snapshot of the *current* rows and cells in the table.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ okay. Do you think using `getElementsByTagName` with the appropriate tag type would be a better choice (in terms of browser compatibility now and in the future) than using `rows` or `cells`?

Comment: @StevenLu: With respect to compatibility, `gEBTN()`, `.rows` and `.cells` all have full cross-browser support, so you won't gain anything going either direction, now or in the future. I do think that it's a bit wasteful to use a method call to retrieve a collection of DOM elements that you already have accessible as a property. The only time I'd use `gEBTN()` to get cells or rows would be if you had nested tables, and wanted to get an aggregate of the cells or rows that includes the nested ones.

Comment: Gotcha. Yes they do have potentially quite different use cases.